# facebook send button returns error, status code 200

Tags: facebook

Send button embedded in page app returns:

'The page at http://www.facebook.com/pages/Page-Name/214575518627336 could not be reached because the server returned status code 200.'

Already checked out the one thread I could find with this error - URL does not redirect.  The http traffic when you click the send button looks roughly like

GET
/plugins/send_button_form_shell.php?api_key=281644568563403&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%23cb%3Df67ca866b77404%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.CanvasURL.com%252Ff17f7ecc54064b4%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&colorscheme=light&controllerID=uguhyi_1&locale=en_US&nodeURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPage-Name%2F214575518627336&sdk=joey HTTP/1.1

and the resulting response is what appears to be a correct serving of the Facebook page.  Also, I can go to the URL directly in browser, sniffing traffic, and verify that it does not redirect.  Plus I have used almost identical code in a previous app and it worked fine.

Anybody have any thoughts?  I have a $5000 app that isn't being deployed because of this one issue >:(  I'm making accounts receivable sad.

EDIT:

Opened a bug with facebook, this is the reply I got:

The bug you are subscribed to "send button returns error - server status code 200" has been updated:
Status has changed: New → By Design
Admin Message has changed: → This is because Facebook URLs are not scraped by the debugger, send plugin only works with non-facebook URLs.

If the send button only works on non-facebook URLs, why does it work in my other apps that reference facebook URLs, and why is this nowhere in the docs?  I'm gonna have to call BS, Facebook.

Comment: how have you implemented the send button? html5, xfbml or iframe? Also, if there is a redirect in place, it might be that it's trying to redirect to the facebook page within facebook.I know if facebook has an iframe with itself in it tends to error

Comment: are you using (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) this send button?

Comment: @ TommyB - Sorry, should have added that - implementing the send button via <fb:send> (XFBML).  Like button works fine in same page so the FB JS SDK seems ok.  I cannot see anywhere a redirect is occurring, every HTTP request results in a 200 status (no 301/302), but I'm not totally sure I understand what you mean about redirects...

@ DMCS - Yes, via XFBML.

Many thanks to both of y'all for your time, I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on with this one.

Comment: Send button works with a different URL and also works when embedded in a different page and referencing the new parent page's URL.  All I can think of is that the original parent page has been 'blacklisted' from being the target of send buttons?  Has anyone heard of this?

Comment: Opened a bug with facebook, this is the reply I got:  

The bug you are subscribed to "send button returns error - server status code 200" has been updated:  
Status has changed: New → By Design  
Admin Message has changed: → This is because Facebook URLs are not scraped by the debugger, send plugin only works with non-facebook URLs.  

If the send button only works on non-facebook URLs, why does it work in my other apps that reference facebook URLs, and why is this nowhere in the docs?  I'm gonna have to call BS, Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I should go ahead and answer this because it's gotten a lot of views.  Facebook doesn't scrape its own pages, the Facebook send plugin only works with non-Facebook URLs.

In my experience, you CAN use the send plugin in a page tab app, but you cannot point it to the app page.  Eg - if you have a page tab app, the send plugin usually works when you point it to the base facebook page, like

```
http://www.facebook.com/AwesomeCompany
```

but it will fail if you point it to the embedded app, like

```
http://www.facebook.com/AwesomeCompany/app_1234567890123456789
```

:)